# COUNT(*) in Web SQL is not working

Tags: web-sql

I am using following code to get the count of records in emp table, code is as follows :

```
var myDb = initDB();  
    myDb.transaction(function(trans) {  
    var query = "SELECT COUNT(*) AS c from emp";  
        trans.executeSql(query, [], function(trans, res) {  
           var count = res.rows[0].c;  
           console.log("--- After Count ---"+count);  
     }, errorHandler); });

The query is giving error : Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'c' of undefined.  
How to solve this issue?
Appreciate any help.
```

Comment: The query appears to be executing correctly, the problem seems to be `res.rows[0].c`. Not sure what type `rows[0]` is returning but given it's a row/col type result have you tried `res.rows[0][0]`?

Comment: I tried ... 
var count = res.rows[0][0];
Getting error : Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined

Comment: it sounds like your table is empty...

Comment: I am inserting a record in the table and getting the count from the table

Comment: I would put my money on that insert failing.

Comment: console.log("results.rows.length :"+res.rows.length+) --- I can see the result on console: results.rows.length :1

Comment: Hmm ok so it's as if web-sql doesn't understand the `Count(*)` query, strange.

Comment: Similar problem [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7816509/web-sql-select-transaction-return-value) and the answer appears to reference the rows as `rows.item(i)` rather than `row[index]`, you could try that. Also it also mentions that you should be using callbacks because `transaction` has a delayed response.

Answer (score 0):

```
html5.webdb.Count=function() {
    var db = html5.webdb.db;
  db.transaction(function (tx) {
    tx.executeSql('SELECT COUNT(*) AS c FROM yourtable', [], function (tx, r) {
      console.log( r.rows.item(0).c);
    }, function (tx, e) {
      alert ("unknown: " + e.message);
    });
  });
}
```

I use this in my db, thanks to James

Answer (score 0):

I have describe below code it will always work and proper way to access Count(*)

```
select COUNT(*) totalCount from tableName
```

so you can access return count by accessing totalCount

```
console.log(r.rows.item(0).totalCount);
```