# Call Javascript function to get resultset of sql query and print them in html table

Tags: javascript, jquery, cordova

I am using Phonegap and jquery-Mobile-1.4.5 to create a cross platform App. Since I am a Java developer , Java script is a very new concept for mine. 
I am creating a simple app where I have one html table where I want to show a select query from a database table . From [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7816509/web-sql-select-transaction-return-value) I found how to send a callback to  functions.
But my problem is ,

1. `onload` is not calling my `showContact(resultSet`) function
2. How can I print the `resultSet` in the <`tbody>` tag, I do not want to use javascript concatenation inside the `showContact(resultSet)` function.

Part of my index.html file

```
<table data-role="table" id="table-custom-2"  onload="showContact(resultSet)" >
            <thead>
                <tr class="ui-bar-d">
                    <th>Id</th>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>Number</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>

                <!--Print the resultSet data with a for loop here-->
            </tbody>

        </table>
```

My javascript code

```
function showContact(resultSet){

             var db= window.openDatabase("appDb","1.0","appDb",200000);

                selectRow("SELECT * FROM contact;", function(resultSet) {
                    console.log(resultSet);

                //Don't want to access the <table> from here
                  });
        }

        /** Select Row from Table **/ 
        function selectRow(query, callBack){ 
           var result = [];
           db.transaction(function (tx) {
              tx.executeSql(query, [], function(tx, rs){
                 for(var i=0; i<rs.rows.length; i++) {
                    var row = rs.rows.item(i)
                    result[i] = { id: row['id'],
                                  name: row['name'],
                                  number: row['number']
                    }
                 }
                 callBack(result); 
              }, errorHandler);
           });
        }
```

Comment: You can use a template system like mustache to render javascript objects into html code https://github.com/janl/mustache.js

Comment: For 1: Look for errors in the console log to troubleshoot. Also consider not putting calls in `onload`, but using `addEventListener` instead. For 2: You'll need to either use a templating solution like @EmanuelRalha suggests, or use the JavaScript DOM API (e.g., `createElement`, `createTextNode` and `insertAfter`) to build up your table rows and append them to your `tbody`. The DOM API is a little tricky to get used to, but if you've worked with XML docs in Java, the concepts are similar.

Comment: @Palpatim : Thanks , can you give an example how to call addEventListener in this scenario

Comment: For cleanliness, refactor `showContact` to not take a parameter, but rather retrieve it upon invocation. Then you can have this in your script code: `document.getElementById('table-custom-2').addEventListener('load', showContact);` BTW, since you never showed where `resultSet` is coming from, that could be a source of bugs as well. Make sure you know it's initialized when you invoke `showContact`

Answer (score 0):

You can frame the data you get from DB in a table row and assign it to the table body. See following code,

You can call the function `selectrow()` when the page loads

```
<table data-role="table" id="table-custom-2">
<thead>
    <tr class="ui-bar-d">
        <th>Id</th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Number</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody id="contactlist">
<!--Print the resultSet data with a for loop here-->
</tbody>
</table>

<script>
$(document).ready(function($) {
    var db= window.openDatabase("appDb","1.0","appDb",200000);
    selectrow();
}); 

function selectrow(){
    db.transaction(function (tx) {
        tx.executeSql("SELECT * FROM contact", [], function(tx, rs){
            var output = '';
            for(var i=0; i<rs.rows.length; i++) {
                var row = rs.rows.item(i)
                output += '<tr><td>' + row['id'] + '</td><td>' + row['name'] + '</td><td>' + row['number'] + '</td></tr>';
            }
            $('#contactlist').html(output);

        }, errorHandler);
    });
}
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks , but you might have missed what I really meant , I don't want to use concatenation inside selectRow

Comment: @Nusrat In that case, you can use Angular JS to pass the data you get in `selectrow()` function and build the contact list. [Check this link](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat)